How to properly nest CSS classes in CSS modules?
Let's say I have the following CSS module:
.someClass {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.someClass .mantine-Checkbox-inner {
  background-color: green;
}

This will be converted to something like:
._someClass_whatever {
  background-color: yellow;
}

._mantine-Checkbox-inner_whatever2 {
  background-color: green;
}

But what I want is something like:
._someClass_whatever {
  background-color: yellow;
}

._someClass_whatever .mantine-Checkbox-inner {
  background-color: green;
}

How can I achieve this?
Please be aware that I will not set CSS class mantine-Checkbox-inner by myself, it will be set by a React component library.
[EDIT] It seems that something like this is working, but this solution is awful, isn't it?
.someClass {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.someClass [class~='mantine-Checkbox-inner'] {
  background-color: green;
}


Oh, it's actually quite simple.
This should do the trick:
.someClass {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.someClass :global(.mantine-Checkbox-inner) {
  background-color: green;
}


And this should work in modern browsers:
.someClass {
  background-color: yellow;

  :global(.mantine-Checkbox-inner) {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

